No USB devices detected on 22.04
I have a desktop computer with GL852G USB controller. When I run Windows 7 the USB ports are working OK. When I run Ubuntu none of my USB sticks are detected. Here is the output:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i usb
[    0.464738] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [USBC]
[    0.691678] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.691716] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.691734] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.691749] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.989472] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.989522] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.989560] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.883910] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.885491] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    2.885507] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    2.885605] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    2.885611] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.885615] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.885618] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-112-generic xhci-hcd
[    2.885621] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.885854] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.887924] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    2.887934] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.887938] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.887941] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-112-generic xhci-hcd
[    2.887944] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.899190] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   35.587675] audit: type=1400 audit(1718291948.091:43): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=808 comm="apparmor_parser"

The output of 'dmesg' and 'lsusb' commands doesn't change if I connect or disconnect my USB sticks. They are completely ignored.
I have found some discussion of the USB hub. But I don't know how to solve the problem. Same thing happens when I run linux kernel 6.9.3 (installed with 'mainline' command).

Can you boot using the default kernel (that is installed and kept updated by default) and confirm the same results?

As I understand, 5.15.0 is the kernel that goes with 'do-release-upgrade' (from 20.04, which had the same issues):   1$ mainline --list-installed mainline 1.4.10 Notice: "--list-installed" has been renamed to "list-installed" Installed Kernels: linux-image-5.11.0-43-generic linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic linux-image-generic linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-43-generic linux-image-unsigned-5.19.17-051917-generic linux-image-unsigned-6.9.3-060903-generic mainline: done
$ uname -r 5.15.0-112-generic

See How to enable HWE on Ubuntu 22.04 for officially supported newer kernels for Ubuntu 22.04. I believe it is 6.8 these days.

@user68186 After I run the command sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 I've got the menu entry in GRUB called '6.5.0-35-generic'. There is no 'hwe' suffix and the issue with USB didn't change. Am I did something wrong?
$ uname -r 6.5.0-35-generic

I may be wrong about 22.04 having 6.8 kernel. I don't have Ubuntu 22.04 near me to verify. You didn't do anything wrong. At least we ruled out that it is not the kernel.

I suppose it somehow related to the kernel module 'linux-usb', because: 1) in the discussion mentioned above they say "enable power to usb hub"; 2) when I insert my USB stick the LED on this stick doesn't light. It means there is no power either on the stick or on the LED.
